# Rule or code in InfoPath 2010 close the browser window

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sharepoint, infopath

When you close a browser form, either via the Close ribbon button, or via the Close action in rules, when the source parameter isn't specified, the page "The Form has been closed appears".

In Infopath web based forms the rules have execution preference over code. Also in UAT or Prod server the Active X controls are blocked because of security features.

How can close this browser window with some rules or code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following post, I think is what you are looking for.

http://johnliu.net/blog/2011/6/17/infopath-2010-close-the-browser-window.html

Cheers!